# How come despite having a match in the excel worksheet, the Application.Match function is not working how it should?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is below:

```
Private Sub txtv_AfterUpdate()
Total_rows_Entries = Worksheets("Entries").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If IsError(Application.Match(txtv.Value, Worksheets("Entries").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Entries), 0)) = False Then
    MsgBox "This voucher number has already been used previously. Voucher numbers cannot be duplicated."
End If

End Sub
```

txtv.Value is a numeric type and it's the textbox value.

The worksheet is shown below:
[image: Worksheet]

My purpose for matching is if there is already a number of "123" in the worksheet, then it should return the messagebox, but it's always bypassing it no matter if I change the type to `.Text` or `.Value` or changing the cell type in excel manually to either general, text, or number.

Comment: Are you sure that txtv is a number and matching Column A's design? What happens if you hardcode in a number? Example: `IsError(Application.Match(3, Worksheets("Entries").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Entries), 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this wide comparison.

```
If not (IsError(Application.Match(clng(txtv.Value), Worksheets("Entries").columns(1), 0)) And _
        IsError(Application.Match(cstr(txtv.Value), Worksheets("Entries").columns(1), 0))) Then
    MsgBox "This voucher number has already been used previously." & vblf & _
           "Voucher numbers cannot be duplicated."
End If
```

Alternately, try something only marginally more calculation intensive but which doesn't care whether the value it is looking for is a string or numeric.

```
If cbool(Application.countif(Worksheets("Entries").columns(1), txtv.Value)) Then
    MsgBox "This voucher number has already been used previously." & vblf & _
           "Voucher numbers cannot be duplicated."
End If
```

Comment: Good call on the `cbool(` function. I earned my second "sportsmanship" tick. 98 more until I get a badge.... 

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess that this has to do with your column being numbers and your match item being string values, or vice versa.

Try this:

```
Private Sub txtv_AfterUpdate()
Total_rows_Entries = Worksheets("Entries").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If IsError(Application.Match(INT(txtv.Value), Worksheets("Entries").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Entries), 0)) = False Then
    MsgBox "This voucher number has already been used previously. Voucher numbers cannot be duplicated."
End If

End Sub
```

Or if it's the other way around try:

```
Private Sub txtv_AfterUpdate()
Total_rows_Entries = Worksheets("Entries").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If IsError(Application.Match(CStr(txtv.Value), Worksheets("Entries").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Entries), 0)) = False Then
    MsgBox "This voucher number has already been used previously. Voucher numbers cannot be duplicated."
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Range.Find` method, which will find numbers stored as either numbers or text:

```
Private Sub txtv_AfterUpdate()
    If Not Worksheets("Entries").Range("A:A").Find(What:=txtv.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This voucher number has already been used previously. Voucher numbers cannot be duplicated."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is this code will say there is a duplicate for example, 3, if it finds a 3 value in a cell with 123. So it is not performing exactly as needed

Comment: Right that makes sense now. Thanks a lot for the help